# Como enviar sms usando javascript ou angular ou node.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, sms

Necessito de um método ou api que envie sms gratuitamente, pode ser do meu número mesmo da tim(tenho plano de sms), procurei e apenas achei algumas pagas de fácil uso. Estou me preparando para um hackathon da universidade e preciso de produzir isso para ter um diferencial no produto final. O app será em angularjs, ionic e as apis em nodejs. Existe alguma maneira de fazer?

Comment: pode exemplificar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conheço usando Firebase e Zapier.

```
var sendSMSText = function (recipient) {
var smsQueue = new Firebase('https://.firebaseio.com/sms/' + recipient.phone);
smsQueue.set({
  name: recipient.name,
  phone: recipient.phone
}, onSuccess)
};
```

Acesse esse blog para saber mais: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/sms-notifications-angularjs-firebase-twilio.html

Ou

Usando o celular diretamente: http://pointdeveloper.com/send-sms-nativescript-angular-2/